# WordPress redirection code not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I'm having trouble getting a WordPress redirection code to work as expected and would appreciate any advice you can offer.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have several domain names that are redirected to my main website, let's call it target.com. For each redirected domain name, I want to redirect the visitor to a specific product page on target.com. For example, if source1.com is redirected to target.com, I want the visitor to be redirected to target.com/product/source1-com.

To achieve this, I've tried using a code in WordPress, but so far I haven't been able to get it to work properly. Here's the code that I've been using:

```
function custom_redirect() {
    // Get the REQUEST_URI header
    $request_uri = isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : '';

    // Check if the REQUEST_URI header matches the pattern of a redirected domain name
    preg_match( '/https?:\/\/([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]+)/i', $request_uri, $matches );
    $redirected_domain = isset( $matches[1] ) ? $matches[1] : '';
    if ( $redirected_domain ) {
        // Construct the target URL for the product page based on the redirected domain name
        $product_page_url = 'https://target.com/product/' . str_replace( '.', '-', $redirected_domain );
        wp_redirect( $product_page_url );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_redirect' );
```

The problem I'm having is that when I visit any of the redirected domain names, I'm always redirected to target.com instead of the specific product page. I've checked that the code is properly added to my WordPress site's functions.php file(snippet) and that the product page URLs are correct, but I'm not sure what else to try.

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas on what might be causing this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I have "All 404 Redirect to Homepage" and "301 redirects pro" plugins. I already disabled them but had the same result. Where can I find your errordocument?

Comment: One word of warning: browsers, specifically Chrome, tend to remember redirects, so when testing this, don’t redirect, just dump to screen and die.

Comment: I don’t usually recommend plugins, however there’s a free one called Redirection with over 2 million installs, and it supports matching on host name. I write a lot of code, but trust this for redirects and such.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - that is only the part after the domain name. You are trying to match that with an expression that will match a full, absolute URL starting with `http(s)`.

Comment: I tried this too but not working(+I disabled all redirect plugins):
function custom_redirect() {
    // Get the HTTP_REFERER header
    $referer = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';